# SMTP server for Python parser

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, python

I'm trying to get emails into a Python application.  There is an exchange server that marks some emails with a BCC address for archive@somedomain.com. I do not control the Exchange server.  The email volume may be high sometimes too.  On the server that will be handling the mail send to the archive address, there is a Python application that parses the emails, inserts some header information to some databases, and stores the email in an object store. I'm not sure of the best way to receive the email and get it into the Python program.

There are a few issues with a Postfix solution.
1) Postfix is a lot of moving parts for such a simple purpose. Not really a big deal if problem 2 can be dealt with.
2) There isn't a good way that I can find to get the emails from Postfix to a Python program.  This is not a Python script that should be invoked each time using the pipe transport. I need a way to stream email contents into the Python application with some kind of deliminator.

I'm also trying to avoid using Pythons smtpd library directly as it uses asyncore which should be avoided in favor of asyncio.

Is there a good Postfix configuration or perhaps another mail SMTP server application that can do what I need? Or will I have to resort to using a Postfix pipe running a script that will insert the email into some kind of queue?  I'm also find with some kind of deliminated rotating log file containing email body and attachment data.

Comment: `I need a way to stream email contents into the Python application with some kind of deliminator.`  - Why?  Why not a pipe transport?  Can you just build yourself a pipe transport that communicates with another script that will do the streaming you require?  You understand that email is not received asynchronously  So expect postfix to make something that is asynchronous magically into something that is synchronous (steam + delimiter) probably isn't going to happen.

Comment: It's not a bad idea.  I was thinking about Unix sockets, but emails are pretty big for single packets (my understanding is, for Unix sockets, a message has to fit in contiguous memory).  That said, you just made me think that maybe I could do something simple over TCP localhost. To my Python app, a server handling TCP connections is pretty simple to make.